# Localstack 404 on lambda Add-Permissions

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, localstack

I'm trying to add permissions to my lambda to be able to use the Kinesis::PutRecord function, but it returns 404 when I try and use the add-permission command.

Overall, I am trying to write a JSON object to a kinesis stream with a lambda, and then read it out with a lambda on the other end. To do this I have a producer lambda that is using PutRecord to put the object into the stream, but that errors out with "The security token included in the request is invalid.". 
It shouldn't be the actual accessKey or secretAccessKey that is invalid, because localstack says in their documentation that they don't check these fields. So, now I am trying to use add-permission from the command line to give my lambda access to this kinesis function, but it errors out.

Here is command I am running to grant permission to my lambda.

```
awslocal lambda add-permission --function-name producer --principal lambda.amazonaws.com --action kinesis:PutRecord --statement-id KinesisPut --source-arn 'MyArnHere'
```

The result:

```
An error occurred (404) when calling the AddPermission operation: <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 3.2 Final//EN">
<title>404 Not Found</title>
<h1>Not Found</h1>
<p>The requested URL was not found on the server. If you entered the URL manually please check your spelling and try again.</p>
```

I should be getting a confirmation or some type of JSON object dump, but instead I am getting this 404 message. I believe this problem is only on localstack and not on AWS because multiple people have been able to do it using aws cli, but there is an open bug report on GitHub for the same problem.

Github Issue (Don't know if its actually an issue):
https://github.com/localstack/localstack/issues/1260